# Underground Feeder Wire OK in Basement?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I need to run a 60 AMP subpanel and have about a 45' total wire run between the main panel and the proposed location of the subpanel. I have a piece of underground feeder cable (6 gauge copper with 10 gauge bare wire).

This is a residential installation, single family.

My question is, would there be any reason I can't use the UG feeder in the basement? It's the gray, flat wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UF cable any place where you might use NM-B cable indoors.

Art 334 is NM cable

Art 340 is UF cable

**NEC 2011**

**Article 340
Underground Feeder and Branch-Circuit Cable: Type UF**

**II. Installation**

**340.10 Uses Permitted**

Type UF cable shall be permitted as follows:

(1)    For use underground, including direct burial in the earth. For underground requirements, see 300.5.

(2)    As single-conductor cables. Where installed as single-conductor cables, all conductors of the feeder grounded conductor or branch circuit, including the grounded conductor and equipment grounding conductor, if any, shall be installed in accordance with 300.3.

(3)    For wiring in wet, dry, or corrosive locations under the recognized wiring methods of this Code.

(4)    Installed as nonmetallic-sheathed cable. Where so installed, the installation and conductor requirements **shall comply with Parts II and III of Article 334** and shall be of the multiconductor type.*